# Create geometry from WKT in FME

Tags: geometry, well-known-text, fme-form

How to create geoemtry from WKT in FME?

We have a csv file in WKT format:

```
"ID";"GEOM"
"1";"LINESTRING ( 15, 20 16, 20 21, 12)"
"2";"LINESTRING ( 15, 20 16, 20 21, 12)"
"3";"LINESTRING ( 15, 20 16, 20 21, 12, 23, 14)"
```

I found  this article: https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/56486/converting-from-csv-data-2.html

But it shows how to split data into points and create a line.

**Is there a simpler way?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [GeometryReplacer](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2018.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/geometryreplacer.htm) transformer will do this for you.

Set the geometry encoding parameter to: OGC Well Known Text (wkt)

From the documentation:

> The OGC variants are useful if interaction with other OGC supporting
>   systems is required. However, some characteristics of geometries may
>   have been lost in these modes; for instance, any path will be
>   flattened into a single linestring. For OGC Well Known Text and OGC
>   Well Known Binary, if measures are specified in the source, they will
>   be saved as the "default" (unnamed) measure on the generated geometry.
>
> When converting from WKT or WKB, if the specified attribute has a
>   blank value, the feature's geometry will be left untouched and a
>   warning will be output.  This is important to remember if a
>   GeometryExtractor was used to generate an attribute which was used in
>   this transformer, because that transformer produces an empty value
>   whenever it encounters a feature with no geometry.

It's also important to note the OGC WKT Precision parameter.

> If Geometry Encoding is OGC Well Known Text, this parameter can be
>   used to control the precision used when converting numerical strings
>   to floating point.